# How can I inspect exceptions thrown by c# compiler?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, compiler-construction, csc

The compiler failed with the following message:
"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

I know this has something to do with serialization (as soon as I uncomment a method tagged with [OnSerialized] the build fails.

How can I inspect LoaderExceptions?  Or more generally speaking how can I trap and inspect any exceptions thrown by c# compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running csc.exe under windbg.exe and inspect the managed exceptions getting thrown.  If there's a particular first chance exception that you need to break on, you can issue the `sxe <exception>` command.  Then, load the sos.dll (`.loadby sos.dll mscorwks`) extension and inspect the exception getting thrown with `!pe`.

Comment: Any easier way to do this? =)

Comment: I tried "sxe ReflectionTypeLoadException" but that doesn't seem to work.  I'm fairly new to WinDbg.  Could you tell me what to put after sxe?